# How to add MFA to Windows 11 Professional RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

I want to add MFA to my Windows 11 computer when connecting with RDP from outside my home network. I don't own Azure AD and this is not for a corporate environment. Is this possible? If MFA is not possible, can I log in with a certificate and disable basic authentication when logging in with RDP?

I am not interested in third party tools. I would like to keep the solution as simple as possible. For example, I have MFA enabled on my microsoft account with the Microsoft Authenticator app. If possible it would be nice to reuse this when I connect over RDP.

Comment: What MFA solution are you looking to use exactly? YubiKey authentication, or similar solutions, are not trivial to setup.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Please add answers to any questions asked in the comments by EDITING your original question. Your question lacks a lot of critical data, and it is in your best interest that you make edit it to make it better.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not interested in third party solutions. If possible I'd like to re-use the existing MFA provided by the Microsoft Authenticator app.

Comment: Well you can’t accomplish what you want without Azure AD. There is a third-party AD service, that supposedly would work, but I can’t recommend it as I don’t have personal experience with it. Microsoft decided to offer MFA through Azure, instead of allowing with their on premises AD option